# comparing two xml file contents in xquery

Tags: java, xml, xquery, basex

I am trying to create a new xml file without giving any path that means it shouldn't be store in my system(disk)(See the class NewXML). Now i want to check this xml into database('db') if it is exist then compare the contents of this xml file with existing xml file into database('db') and if contents are same then it should be return true otherwise false(See the class CheckXML ).

Notice that why i don't want to store new xml file into disk because if file is stored in disk then first of all i need to read it after that we can compare it with exist file inside the database which is not feasible solution. It raises the performance issue when we try to compare millions of xml files.
 So please guys anyone can resolve this problem.If you have any other way please let me know.

```
public class NewXML
{

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws QueryException 
     * @throws BaseXException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        CheckXML cXml=new CheckXML();
        System.out.println("Enter value to create the records:");
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);

        int i = kb.nextInt();
        try 
        {
                DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                // root elements
                Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();


                Element rootElement = (Element) doc.createElement("ABC");
                doc.appendChild(rootElement);

                // staff elements
                Element staff = doc.createElement("DEV");
                rootElement.appendChild(staff);

                // set attribute to staff element
                String id=String.valueOf(i);


                Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
                attr.setValue(id);
                staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

                // shorten way
                // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

                // firstname elements
                String fn="yong"+i;


                Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
                firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(fn));
                staff.appendChild(firstname);

                // lastname elements
                String ln="mook kim"+i;

                Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
                lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(ln));
                staff.appendChild(lastname);

                // nickname elements
                String nicknm="mkyong"+i;

                Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
                nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nicknm));
                staff.appendChild(nickname);

                // salary elements
                Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
                salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
                staff.appendChild(salary);

                //target name
                //Node node=dom.c


                // write the content into xml file
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "staff");
                transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");


                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);


                String xmlfilename = "Staff_Member"+""+id+".xml";

                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

                transformer.transform(source, result);

                System.out.println(xmlfilename);

            //""""""""""CHECK AND COMPARE XML FILE CONTENTS  INTO DATABASE""""""""""""  

              cXml.comparingXML(xmlfilename);




        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException pce)
        {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (TransformerException tfe) 
        {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BaseXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (QueryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

public class CheckXML
{/*
    public static void main(String[] args) throws QueryException, IOException {
*/      DatabaseConnection processor = new DatabaseConnection();
//Database context.
        Context context = new Context();



      public void comparingXML(String xml) throws BaseXException, QueryException
      {

        System.out.println("\n* Open collection database");

        new Open("db").execute(context);

        String xmlFile=xml;

        System.out.println(xmlFile);

        // System.out.println("=================Comparing XML files====================");




        String query = "declare variable $xml-file as xs:string external;" +
                   "for $doc in collection('db')where matches(document-uri($doc), '" + xmlFile + "') return deep-equal($doc, $xml-file)";

        QueryProcessor proc = new QueryProcessor(query, context);

        proc.bind("xml-file", xmlFile);

        Result result = proc.execute(); // your result
        System.out.println(result);



  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Close the database context
        context.close();


        }



}
```

Comment: also, your question contains too many redundant code, it's not clear what you want to show.

Comment: @arghtype Your comment "Do you think, you are the first one to face such problem?" is rather rude. If you think it is a duplicate, then please flag it as such. Otherwise it would be better to say nothing instead of such aggressive wording. It really helps no-one.

Comment: @dirkk didn't mean any offense, removed it anyway. as for subject, i could recommend to search for a framework for xml comparsion. For example, I used classes from XMLUnit in such case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think your whole approach is neither performant nor elegant. You only have a small number of elements, so it would be much easier (and much more performant) to check with some simply XPath if an element with a specific name, nickname and salary already exists instead of comparing an serializing whole documents.

Comment: Actually, as you are using BaseX, the whole thing could (and should!) be done using XQuery Update and the database module from BaseX. Using that, you can dynamically add and transform new documents using XQuery. Take a look at https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Updates and https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module

Comment: hi dirkk, i am getting the result 'false' whether contents are same or not and the code is same as given in above.Even yesterday i asked one more question, is it possible to use deep-equal($doc, doc($xml-file) )instead of ($doc, $xml-file )?

Comment: hi dirkk, is it possible to pass dom object directly in deep-equal function?

Comment: Please use the @ operator in comments before a user name, otherwise I won't get notified (and will not see your comment).  I am not sure if it is possible to bind an arbitrary `item()` from java to XQuery - it will certainly not be very efficient. As said above, if you want this to be fast, you should probably use XQuery Update instead of DOM manipulation.

Comment: Two things come to mind here - first, can you compute (and store in the db) a hash of each document in the database, compute the hash of your data, and only proceed if there's a match? Second, can you query BaseX as you construct the document in memory to find a match, instead of loading it and comparing?